# Connecting to a RESTful API from Xamarin.Forms mobile application (and other computers on the same network)

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am trying to connect my Xamarin.Forms mobile application to a RESTful API I'm hosting locally on my computer. I'm using Visual Studio for both the Xamarin.Forms mobile application and for the API, and for the API, I'm using ASP.NET Core (the specific template in Visual Studio is ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) ). 

It worked fine when I connected to it from my browser using a localhost address on the same computer I ran the API from (in my case, localhost:59475/api/ was the URL) and before connecting my mobile application to the API, I first tried to connect to the API from other computers on the same network, and I didn't manage to make it work so far. What I tried so far is the following - run the cmd command `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:59475/ user=everyone` (along with other similar commands with other ports I thought may work), then I added an inbound firewall rule to allow all connections on that port. I then tried to connect to the API from other computers on the network by replacing "localhost" in the address with the IP of the computer running the API, and I received an HTTP 503 error when I did. Evantually what happend is when I tried to run the API from Visual Studio it showed an error of

> Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'

"Undoing" the netsh http commands (netsh http delete urlacl...) made it work again as it did at first (again, only able to connect to it from the same computer using my browser). I don't know how to make it work and would like to receive help please! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. add your external IP explicitly `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.0.6:60985/ user=everyone`
2. In the root of the API solution folder open the '.vs/config/applicationhost.config' file (.vs is hidden by default)
3. in the bindings section add a new binding to the external address `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60985:192.168.0.6" />`, mind to which site you are adding the bindings as there could be multiple.

Notes: example port 60985 yours could be different check the api
example IP: 192.168.0.6, change to your actual external IP address

You might want to disable the firewall for testing then when you confirm it works, enable it and add an exception rule

Comment: @AlexanderMarkovski it seems that after I executed the command netsh http add urlacl etc. the error of "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'" appears again.

Comment: @HarelDanieli 503 usually happens if the config I mentioned is not set properly. what did you enter for bidning in the config exactly?

Comment: I followed your instructions replacing the IP and Port you put with my computer's IP and the port used by my API.

Comment: Double check that what you entered in the binding matches what you set for the netsh command, disable the firewall, restart vs and try again, and also start vs as admin.

Comment: I tried it again, there was already a binding in the config file to localhost so I tried with it and the binding to the IP AND only with the binding to the IP (without the localhost binding), both times cleaning the build and restarting VS and neither worked

Comment: Keep both localhost and external and check if you have multiple sites, you could be adding bindings to the wrong site.

Comment: There were indeed 2 sites there, I made sure I'm changing the binding to the one which is the API and not the other one there, also I tried it with both the localhost and IP binding **and** with only the IP and neither works.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is to try adding the bindings to the other site, and be sure to start VS as admin.

Comment: I'm not sure how (the only change I made as far as I can remember since the last time I tested it was to move the binding line of the IP beneath the localhost binding line and align it [visually] with the other lines) but it works now! Thank you! :D
I tested it with my mobile application and it works too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved with the magical Conveyor extension.
https://keyoti.com/products/conveyor/index.html?utm_source=conveyor&utm_medium=extension_moreinfo&utm_campaign=conveyor

Follow the guide on their website.
In netcore, disable SSL first (project property => debug)