# How to Authenticate a xamarin.Forms app using AAD

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie to Mobile app and took a new project recently. I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms App and trying to get an access token from Azure Active Directory in order able to get access to some Web API services on an other server.

using this code below I was able to get the response on console app but not from Xamarin.forms.
Q1. How can I implement this functionality in my PCL?

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

internal class UtilityClass
{
    public static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {            
     var authenticationContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, null);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        try
        {
            if (Token == null)
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(audienceApi, clientCredential);
                if (result == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
                Token = result.AccessToken;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return Token;
    }

    public async static Task<TReturn> CallApiAsync<TReturn>(string URI)
    {

        TReturn result = default(TReturn);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(audienceApi);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetTokenAsync());


        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(URI, string.Empty));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturn>(content);
        }

        return result;
     }
  }
```

with in my PCL's app Method, try to access it this way

```
public App ()
{
    var CustomerContactList = UtilityClasses.CallApiAsync<List<CustomerContact>>(); 
}
```

Q2. I want to run my web API service on a local server and debug the call from Xamarin.Forms App, so how can I configure my Visual Studio 2015 and Android Emulator to get access to https://localhost:PortNumber/api/getCustomerContacts?

Thank You in Advance, for your support

Comment: Answering Q2: you cannot use localhost, specify IP address of your host machine instead. Make sure you host machine and emulator are on the same network. To answer Q1 I will need to test my answer which is impossible without credentials, so sorry

Comment: What I meant to say: your device and your host machine on the same network. For emulator it is obviously on the same network but still need to use IP address sa host and emulator use different IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your local IIS Express to handle requests it receives on your external IP, follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410720/connecting-to-a-restful-api-from-xamarin-forms-mobile-application-and-other-com/45411534?noredirect=1#comment77792873_45411534), debug steps if you get stuck in comments

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. How can I implement this functionality in my PCL?

There is something that is suitable for you if you take a look at this link
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19021/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms

Substitute the auth with the below redirectUrl and authorizeUrl should work, although i haven't tested this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
clientId: "clientId",
scope: "",
authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant}/oauth2/authorize?"),
redirectUrl: new Uri ("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
```

> Q2. I want to run my web API service on a local server and debug the call from Xamarin.Forms App, so how can I configure my Visual Studio 2015 and Android Emulator to get access to https://localhost:PortNumber/api/getCustomerContacts?

In your IIS , expose your local web site in a specific port, then in your android emulator you can use

https://10.0.2.2:portNumber/api/getCustomerContacts